# Detect unit test code coverage of a commit

Tags: unit-testing, junit

Let's say that the language I use is Java and I do a specific commit, is there a way how I can tell the code coverage of a commit or even if it was done? When a user commits to the repository, I want to have multiple statistics about the commit, including unit test coverage on that specific commit. Is this even possible? Are there already such tools out there or do I need to think about something custom?

I am using Git hosted under Gitblit, I alread saw the hook mechanism by Gitblit, thus it is just a matter of how to do this.

Comment: What are you using as version control system?

Comment: Git hosted under Gitblit

Comment: What you're *really* looking for is a Continuous Integration server like Jenkins etc. Then you install plugins to visualise the build's coverage report. There are numerous and most of them should allow "breaking the build" if test coverage drops below a certain threshold.

Comment: Can you give example of a plugin that breaks the build if code coverage drops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working now on that same problem, and I've come out with this approach:

- My projects are Java and Maven based. Every one of them inherits from a common parent.
- In the common parent pom I've set the jacoco-maven-plugin at integration-test phase to calculate the unit tests coverage. The produced report is stored in the same project along with the source code.
- Every time a developer does a commit to the Source Control System, he/she also commits the report, so that I shall query the coverage state for every commit that has been done.

This is already done and working. My next step will be to develop a tool to query the Source Control System (which is SVN in my case) to get the coverage statistics: by date, project, and even by user.

Note that the report generated by Jacoco is *absolute*, not incremental. If you want it incremental (as I want, too), you have to compute the difference between one report and the previous one.

To query SVN I'm currently using `org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit:1.3.8`.

The same procedure can be applied to other code metrics: rules compliance, etc.

Comment: Does the jacoco maven plugin calculate just new code or code coverage based on all existing unit tests? On the third point you mention, how do you query SVN for a specific report of a developer, or by date?

Comment: What I mean is, let's say a developer commits just a new feature, without changing existing code. Let's assume, code coverage is 0% before his commit and that his commit contains 100% code coverage. How does jacoco behave, does it cover all code or just the new commited one? Is there a way based on the commit and the jacoco report to see just for that specific commit the code coverage?

Comment: What are you using to compute the difference between one jacoco report to another in order to obtain an incremental code coverage report?

Comment: In my case, it is a simple computing: Substracting _total_ values.

Comment: You are welcome. Nonetheless, you should also research among Continuous Integration systems, as kryger suggest... In my company they use Sonar for these kind of quality management tasks, but I couldn't find how to get statistics based on users... That's why I had to develop my own solution.